# Retrieving Username Through Airwatch's 'Send Application Configuring' option to Cordova App

Tags: cordova, airwatch

Airwatch has the ability to send application configurations to app. How can I receive username (or any configuration) from Airwatch for Cordova application?

Answer (score 0):

AirWatch SDK doesn't support natively Cordova. To use AirWatch SDK features, you can use Cordova plugins like this one: [airwatch-sdk-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airwatch-sdk-plugin).

For iOS and Android, which are supported by AirWatch SDK, the AirWatch developpers website recommands integrating the AirWatch SDK into your app and configure a SDK profile with Integrated Authentification. You have basic documentation here: [developer.air-watch.com/single-sign-on/](http://developer.air-watch.com/single-sign-on/)

Comment: I have installed airwatch plugin, but I dont want it to redirect to airwatch agent to authenticate. I just wanted to retrieve username from the enrolled device.. How do I stop this auto redirection and jus use username function to retrieve username? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: https://github.com/audioeng/cordova-plugin-appconfig.

In your airwatch console, you need to add "EnrollmentUser" as the key and "{EnrollmentUser}" as the value.

Hope that help.